# Rails 4: comment partial not rendering

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

Trying to display comments for photo, photo belongs to profile.  html does not render.

The pertinent code:

routes.rb

```
  resources :profiles do
    resources :photos do
      resources :comments do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end
```

comments/_comment.html.haml

```
= comments.each do |comment|
  %li
    = comment.body 
    \-
    %small Submitted 
    = #{time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)}

    = semantic_form_for [@profile, @photo, comment, Comment.new] do |f|
      = f.inputs do
        = f.input :body, placeholder: "Add a Reply"
        %br/
      = f.actions do
        = f.action :submit, :as => :input, label: "Reply"
    %ul
      - render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: {comments: comment.comments}
```

models/photo.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

models/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

models/profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

app/controllers/phtos_controller.rb

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_photo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_profile
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @photos = Photo.where(:profile => @profile)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @photo = Photo.new(:profile => @profile)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params.merge(:profile_id => @profile.id))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@profile, @photo], notice: 'Photo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.update(photo_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [@profile, @photo], notice: 'Photo was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @photo.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profile_photos_url, notice: 'Photo was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_photo
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_profile
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:description, :attachment)
  end
end
```

/app/views/photos/show.html.haml

```
= render partial: "layouts/sub_header", locals: {heading:    @photo.profile.name + "'s", sub_heading: "photo", current_bread_crumb: @photo.profile.name + "'s photo", include_crumbs: true}
/ Intro Content
.row
  .col-md-6
    = image_tag @photo.attachment.url(:large), :class => "img-responsive"
  .col-md-6
    %p
      %h2 About this photo...
      = simple_format(@photo.description)
      ,
 / /.row

 %h3 Comments

 = semantic_form_for [@profile, @photo, Comment.new] do |f|
   = f.inputs do
     = f.input :body, :as => :text
   = f.actions do
     = f.action :submit, :as => :input

 %ul
   - render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: {comments: @photo.comments}

 - if current_user == @profile.user
   = link_to 'Edit', edit_profile_photo_path(@profile, @photo)
   |
  = link_to 'Back', :back
```

Data is being inserted into the database (except the profile_id, but I will save that for another post).  I manually updated the profile_id in the db to make see if it was just a data integrity issue, still nothing.

I have tried moving the resources around in the routes.rb, I have tried refactoring the views to load the collection directly without the partial, nothing seems to work.

Additionally, if I comment out the partial and use this code I do see comment bodies on the page, so it is definitely something I am doing wrong in the call to the partial or inside the partial itself.

```
%ul
  - @photo.comments.each do |comment|
    = comment.body
```

I cannot seem to crack this one and I know it isn't magic, but I clearly not seeing something.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How have you established that the comments partial does not render? Have you tried adding some html before the first line to double check?

Comment: I tried to use a puts comment.body.inspect line in the partial, but never got a print of it.

Comment: `puts` goes to standard output which may not be visible or in an obvious place. You can do one of two things, use the logger `- logger.debug('Rendering comments partial')`, then look in your log file. Add some obvious html like: `%div{style:'height:30px;width:200:px;background:red'} Rendered comments`

Comment: Also, once you have fixed the issue, I would suggest restructuring your partial to render only one comment and look at section 3.4.5 Rendering Collections here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: And two more quick things (1) I suspect you will find that your issue is that you have no comments, you can test this by using the rails console or logging the count of comments (2) In your routes file, you have a comments resource inside another comments resource. This is unlikely to be correct

Comment: Thanks Marc, I will look into those things, I was looking for the output of the puts in the runner window in cloud 9 which shows all the output coming from the webserver.  I also looked at the development.log file to try to trace this.  I did verify that in the database I have 6 comments and they all have the photo_id set to the correct object so I am not sure what you mean by no comments.  The reason for the nested resources is that a comment can have a comment, this is a polymorphic relationship.  Not sure it is right, but it is how it was depicted in the examples I was reviewing.

Comment: I read the section you were referring too in guides.rubyonrails.org, nothing jumped out as to what I am doing wrong.  I opened up my rails console and typed in - Photo.find(20).comments and the response brought back many comments, so the photo object and comment object are definitely associated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Change `show.html.haml` to:

```
%ul
  - render 'comments/comment', locals: {comments: @photo.comments}
```

Reason being, is that you can't render a view within a view, so the above will assume you are looking for a partial named `_comment.html.haml` within the comments folder.

Comment: What is the purpose of the partial: then if not to render it inside a view?

Comment: Yeah that is the purpose for a partial, I mean you can't render a full view inside a view, so Rails assumes you are looking for a partial: [the syntax](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#naming-partials) to render a partial from another controller is `render 'folder/partial'`.

Comment: by doing this Jarvis I now get the following error "undefined local variable or method `comments'"

Comment: Looks like your aren't getting the photo object to be passed to the view.  I feel like that has to be an issue in the `show` method of the `photos_controller` - you'll have to do some more digging

Comment: I updated the question to include the PhotosController class.  This was pretty much boiler plate other than I load the picture in a before callback, I would expect that photo would be passed.  Though I am not sure.  Can you see anything wrong in the controller?  Also note I did try it with a @photo = Photo.find(params[:id]) call in the show method, but that had no effect.

Comment: Also Jarvis, the picture does show on the page when I go to the url, so I am not sure what would be wrong that it would not have access to the photo.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Marc and Jarvis for all your help, I still don't know why that wasn't working, but looking at the ActionView::PartialRender at api.rubyonrails.org I found that this does work...

```
  - @photo.comments.each do |comment|
    = render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: comment }
```

I basically have to do the iterating myself even though clearly in the guide Marc referenced it said I should be able to do what I had written.

Oh well, on to the next problem.

Thanks again!

Comment: Something like `= render partial: "comments/comment", collection: @photo.comments` should work

Comment: Yeah I had tried that, actually, that was the original code before I even started mucking about trying to get it to work and it was a no go.